# S3 bucket migration to another region

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Here's the script i made to migrate a bucket to another region

Steps:

- Creates temporary bucket to hold the objects
- Copy objects to temporary bucket
- Delete Main bucket
- Create Main bucket in specified region
- delete temporary bucket

Script:

```
#! /bin/sh

BUCKETNAME=$1
MIGRATION_REGION=$2
TEMPBUCKETNAME="temp-$(uuidgen)"

if [ ! "$2" ];
then
    echo Incorrect arguments supplied
    echo USAGE
    echo     './migrate.sh <bucketname> <region>'
    exit 1
fi

aws s3 mb s3://${TEMPBUCKETNAME} --region $MIGRATION_REGION
aws s3 mv --recursive s3://${BUCKETNAME} s3://${TEMPBUCKETNAME}
aws s3 rb s3://${BUCKETNAME} --force
while true;
do
    echo STILL CREATING BUCKET    
    sleep 5
    aws s3 mb s3://${BUCKETNAME} --region $MIGRATION_REGION || continue
done
aws s3 mv --recursive s3://${TEMPBUCKETNAME} s3://${BUCKETNAME}
aws s3 rb s3://${TEMPBUCKETNAME}
echo BUCKET MIGRATED
```

Now the issue is when you delete a bucket, there is a minimum of one hour delay between the bucket deletion and the name becoming available again.

Im happy to keep this script running for an hour, although during testing i aborted the script while it was looping and when i checked my account the bucket was created even after aborting the script.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How many objects does the bucket have?

Comment: @jellycsc around 5gigs of data, ~1000 files

Comment: You should add `set -e` in your script, so you don't destroy a bucket if the mv fails for any reason.

Comment: @AnonCoward what happens when a move is aborted? cant i just move again?

Comment: Right now in your script if the `aws s3 mv` step fails for any reason, the next step will run and you will lose data in the process.  If you run `set -e` before any steps, if any aws call fails then the script itself will stop.

Comment: @AnonCoward Oh thats actually pretty important. Ill add `set -e` @ the top

Comment: It can take significant time (many hours, perhaps even days) for a bucket name to become available again after deletion. You might want to divide your process into three parts (export, create, import). I would also recommend using `aws s3 sync` to copy the bucket contents since it can easily recover from any issues. Don't delete buckets until your are SURE that all objects have been copied. Your script could incorrectly delete buckets when all objects have _not_ been copied.